# Accordion in the angular 2

Tags: angular, accordion

I am facing some problems with accordion as

[image: this is what created in angular 2]

Here A routes to one page and b to other

what i want is, i want to Accordion this A B C and D
Suppose A contains  Accordion as `A1` `A2` AND `A3` and want to route that `A1`, `A2` and `A3` to other page

So please anyone provide some sample code to do this

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create routes and send data with them in component extract data from router and open appropriate tab.

https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([
   { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
   { path: "A", component: Accordian, data: { open: 'A' } },
   { path: "B", component: Accordian, data: { open: 'B' } },
   { path: "C", component: Accordian, data: { open: 'C' } }
  ])
 ]
})
```